# C - Adding quotes to a user input

Tags: c

I want to add quotes to the input given by the user and cannot figure out how.

```
printf("Please enter a name: ");
    char string[50];

    scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string);
```

After this Id like to be able to add the quotes. So if the user types Bob, it is stored as "Bob". Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Then, write:

```
string[0] = '"';
scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", string + 1);
size_t len = strlen(string);
string[len] = '"';
string[len + 1] = '\0';
```

Call `scanf()` on `string + 1` after storing `'"'` at `string[0]`. Then obtain the length of the string to add another `'"'` to its end.

Comment: Was just in the midst of typing this very same answer, although it's worth checking the return value of `scanf` to make sure something has been entered.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Checking the return value of `scanf()` is good and recommended, but as you can see, the OP did not provide full working code, so am just giving out the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
if(fgets(string,50,stdin)!=NULL){
   char anotherstring[50];
   string[strcspn(string,"\n")]=0;
   int len = (int) strlen(string);
   if(sprintf(anotherstring,"\"%s\"", string) == len+2){
      // anotherstring contains quoted string
   }
}
```

Here you could have used `scanf` - you would have to check the return value of `scanf` to know whether it is successful or not. Better is to use `fgets` - it is much easier to work with than `scanf`.

Also if you use `scanf` you should specify the number of characters that you can read -

```
if(scanf("%49s",string) == 1){
   ...
}
```